VB.net Datatable dynamic columns Query with LINQ
I've the same problem as this: VB.net Datatable dynamic columns Query fields with LINQ
I make a query with a dynamic SELECT then I don't know how many columns I'll have. I know only that I'll have the column of group by (this is a static column in the SELECT) and then I've to make sum and avg for the others but I don't know how much are.
This is an example:
Dim dtGroup = 
    From row In dt
    Group row By dateGroup = New With {
        Key .az = row.Field(Of String)("az")
    } Into Group
    Select New With {
        Key .Company = dateGroup,
            .SumImp = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Decimal)("imp")),
            .SumCl = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Decimal)("cl")),
            .AvgCpc = Group.Average(Function(x) x.Field(Of Decimal)("cpc")),
            .AvgCost = Group.Average(Function(x) x.Field(Of Decimal)("cost")),
            .Count = Group.Count()
    }


How does one date VB.net?
